# How can I get QListWidget item by name?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a `QListWidget` which displays a list of names using PyQt in **Python**. How can I get the `QListWidgetItem` for a given name?

For example, if I have the following `QListWidget` with 4 items, how can I get the item which contains text = dan?

[image: QListWidget]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The python equivalent to vahancho's answer:

```
items = self.listWidgetName.findItems("dan",Qt.MatchExactly)

if len(items) > 0:

    for item in items:
        print "row number of found item =",self.listWidgetName.row(item)
        print "text of found item =",item.text()
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me.

Comment: Qt.MatchExactly is in QtCore, so QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly (if one has not imported all of QtCore)

Comment: Hello may I ask for the opposite of `Qt.MatchExactly`? like for example you are finding "danny" but still there is "dan" on it so it would be still valid... I think Qt has it but I don't know how tho.. have you just in case appliedi t? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use `QListWidget::findItems()` function. For example:

```
QList<QListWidgetItem *> items = listWidget->findItems("dan", Qt::MatchExactly);
if (items.size() > 0) {
    // An item found
}
```

Comment: @panofish post a new answer if you are going to add python logic. This is vahancho answer you should not edit in things that aren't in line with the OP's meaning which he was only posting the example above. Just make a new answer :)

Comment: I am the original poster and I was asking for python logic.  I am thankful to vahancho for guiding me in the right direction, but python is what I was looking for.  If I post a new answer, then I would have to mark my own answer as correct and take away for vahanchos good work.

Comment: @panofish thats the way SO works, its not appropriate to edit someone elses answer beyond their intent. Vahancho would need to make that edit himself. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261224/897794). Why not just upvote if the answer was **useful**.

Comment: @ secretformula, OK, thanks for educating me.  That clears it up.  I will post another answer.  Thanks

Comment: I down-voted this answer as it's not python code. Some of us have absolutely no idea how to code in c++.

Answer (score 3):

```
items = self.listWidgetName.findItems("dan",Qt.MatchContains);
```

This works best while working with `QListWidget` item